# Code generation in Eclipse plug-in

Tags: pointers, code-generation, eclipse-plugin

I'm developing an Eclipse plug-in and I'd like to insert code automatically... sort of create a sample application automatically when the user presses a button. How can I go about it please?

Thanks and regards,
Krt_Malta

Comment: Actually I have no idea... but I guess it's possible since the GUI builders do insert code. Just looking for some enlightment...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to create a project/files, then you have to use the Resource API of Eclipse. For some initial ideas look at http://www.phurnace.com/blog/the-eclipse-resources-plug-in-2.html.

In a similar fashion you could look for existing files and read them.

Answer (score 1):

This did the trick: 
http://wiki.eclipse.org/FAQ_How_do_I_insert_text_in_the_active_text_editor%3F

Answer (score 0):

A pretty straightforward approach to code generation in Eclipse are [Java Emitter Templates](http://www.eclipse.org/articles/Article-JET/jet_tutorial1.html). If your use case involves EMF, you could consider [Xpand](http://wiki.eclipse.org/Xpand). And there are other options in the Eclipse [M2T](http://www.eclipse.org/modeling/m2t/) project.

Answer (score 0):

This helped me out a lot:

http://sdqweb.ipd.kit.edu/wiki/JDT_Tutorial:_Creating_Eclipse_Java_Projects_Programmatically

Using it you can create projects, packages and classes programatically. With some additional code, you could import libraries into the project files programmatically.